# PHP select information

Tags: php, html

I'm having troubles with getting information from my database. It needs to SELECT avatar FROM users. If avatar = NULL, avatarcode = `<a href="user.php?u='.$log_username.'"><img id="profile" src="img/user.png"></a>`, else, avatarcode = `<a href="user.php?u='.$log_username.'"><img id="profile" src="user/'.$log_username.'/'.$avatar.'"></a>`

```html
$sql = "SELECT avatar FROM users";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$avatarcode = "";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $avatar = $row["avatar"];
    if ($avatar = NULL) {
        $avatarcode = '<a href="user.php?u='.$log_username.'"><img id="profile" src="img/user.png"></a>';
    } else {
        $avatarcode = '<a href="user.php?u='.$log_username.'"><img id="profile" src="user/'.$log_username.'/'.$avatar.'"></a>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Comparisons in PHP must never be done with one single "equal" sign, but with two or three (recommended because of typesafe comparison with zero surprises).

```
if ($avatar === NULL) {
```

Comment: +1; In this case _This function sets NULL fields to the PHP NULL value._ ([doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli-result.fetch-array.html)), so we can use strict comparison operators ( === ) without problems

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare empty database string value to `null` compare it to empty string `""`

And to compare value compare with two equal sign `==`

One equal sign is for assignment

And if the value actually is null not empty string compare it using `is_null($avatar)` or `$value === NULL`

you can make your column take null for not supplied value

```
ALTER TABLE `users` CHANGE `avatar` `avatar` VARCHAR(11) NULL;
```

if your not supplied avatar is empty string use:

```
if ($avatar == "") {
```

or if not supplied avatar is null

```
if (is_null($avatar)) {
```